# Is it possible to format an RMarkdown report dashboard style?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

For this use case I cannot use flexdashboard, however I am looking to see if I can create something similar to flexdashboard but in RMarkdown (knitted to html). I am looking to format an RMarkdown report like the format you see below and in a landscape mode. I've only created markdown reports in a portrait style.

[image]

I found this online in a video and I wasn't sure how it was created but this was created in RMarkdown. If there is a way to do this, is it possible someone can share a reproducible example?

[image]